# Interest calculator not displaying results

Tags: java

I'm trying to finish this at the last minute for my Java class, when I run the program after it asks the user if the information is correct, it just loops back to the first question no matter what. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InterestCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userResponse = null;

        do {
            int quartersDisplayed = -1;
            double startingBalance = -1, 
                   interestRate = -1;

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the numbers of quarters you wish to display that is greater than zero and less or equal to 10: ");
                userResponse  = input.next();

                try{
                    quartersDisplayed = Integer.parseInt(userResponse);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if(quartersDisplayed <= 0 || quartersDisplayed > 10) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that value is not valid.");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while(true);


            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the starting balance (must be greater than zero): ");
                userResponse  = input.next();

                try {
                    startingBalance = Double.parseDouble(userResponse);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if(startingBalance <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that value is not valid.");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while(true);


            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the interest rate (greater than zero less than twenty percent): ");
                userResponse  = input.next();

                try {
                    interestRate = Double.parseDouble(userResponse);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if(interestRate <= 0 || interestRate > 20){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that value is not valid.");
                } else {
                    break;
                } 
            } while(true);


            System.out.println("You have entered the following amount of quarters: "
                            + quartersDisplayed);
            System.out.println("You also entered the starting balance of: " + startingBalance);
            System.out.println("Finally, you entered the following of interest rate: "
                            + interestRate);
            System.out.println("If this information is not correct, please exit the program and enter the correct information.");

            double quarterlyEndingBalance = startingBalance + (startingBalance * interestRate / 100 * .25);
            System.out.println("Your ending balance for your quarters is "
                    + quarterlyEndingBalance);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            userResponse = input.next();

            if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(userResponse) || "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(userResponse))
                continue;
            else
                break;

        } while(true);
    }
}
```

What I am looking for as a sample output:

```
Enter number of quarters from 1 to 10
5
Enter the beginning principal balance greater than zero
4500
Enter the interest rate percentage without the percent sign, greater than 0 percent and less than/equal to 20%
3.5
You entered a principal balance of $4500.0 for 5 quarters at 3.5% interest.
Is this correct? (y/n)
y
Quarter       Beginning       Interest       Ending
Number        Balance         Earned         Balance
1             4500.00          39.38         4539.38
```

ect ect

Comment: I think you're confused about what the `continue` statement does.  It means "execute the loop again", not "continue with the code after the loop".  If you want to leave the loop and continue with the code after the loop, use `break`.  Basically you have `continue` and `break` reversed, but the `continue` statement is pretty worthless here anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you ment to do is to restart the loop, if the input was wrong. In this case, you just need to switch the `continue` and the `break`.

The `continue` statement makes a loop immediately start the next iteration. You shoud either remove it by an empty statement `;`, or negate the `if`-condition, remove the `else` and make it `break` on `true`. In addition, your code does nothing else, then getting the input and asking whether it is correct. And as it is written inside a `do...while(true)` loop, this loop will never end. So either remove that loop, or add an option to abort the process.

Comment: I think I understand, I edited the original post, what should I do to get this sample run? Sorry I'm so clueless.

Comment: @jh365 first off: You don't have any code do caculate and print the result. Can you make that on your own, or do you need help with that?

Comment: ahhhhh if you could help me you'd be a legend, but I get it if not this is a lot of work that I need to do on my own, im just clueless

Comment: @jh365 okay, can you join the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) ? I will be wating there.

Comment: it says i need 20 rep :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code should look something like the one below...
**Look out to the bottom, where the user is informed of the values entered  and check for the changes made**. This is quite simple...


import java.util.Scanner;

public class correctstack{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userResponse = null;

        do {
            int quartersDisplayed = -1;
            double startingBalance = -1, 
                   interestRate = -1;

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the numbers of quarters you wish to display that is greater than zero and less or equal to 10: ");
                userResponse  = input.next();

                try{
                    quartersDisplayed = Integer.parseInt(userResponse);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if(quartersDisplayed <= 0 || quartersDisplayed > 10) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that value is not valid.");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while(true);


            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the starting balance (must be greater than zero): ");
                userResponse  = input.next();

                try {
                    startingBalance = Double.parseDouble(userResponse);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if(startingBalance <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that value is not valid.");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while(true);


            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the interest rate (greater than zero less than twenty percent): ");
                userResponse  = input.next();

                try {
                    interestRate = Double.parseDouble(userResponse);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if(interestRate <= 0 || interestRate > 20){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that value is not valid.");
                } else {
                    break;
                } 
            } while(true);


System.out.println("You have entered the following amount of quarters: "+ quartersDisplayed);
System.out.println("You also entered the starting balance of: " + startingBalance);
System.out.println("Finally, you entered the following of interest rate: "+ interestRate);
System.out.println("If this information is not correct, please exit the program and enter the correct information.");

//Here, you give the user the opportunity to continue or re-enter the values. So you go like...

System.out.println("Is this info correct?");

String user_input = input.next();

if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(user_input) || "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(user_input)){

            double quarterlyEndingBalance = startingBalance + (startingBalance * interestRate / 100 * .25);
            System.out.println("Your ending balance for your quarters is "+ quarterlyEndingBalance);


        System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to continue?");
               userResponse = input.next();

            if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(userResponse) || "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(userResponse))
                    continue;
        else
            break;
}   
else
    continue;


        } while(true);
    }
}
```